# java comand works but not javac?

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, javac

ok so I got a new PC

Windows 7 Pro 64 bit Service Pack 1

I installed jdk-7u25-windows-x64 ( jdk 1.7.0_25)

It is installed in default location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

I added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the Path environment variable (yes I used a ; before I added it)

Clicked Ok

Closed all CMD windows opened them up

And now If I run the command java I get the expected output

But If I run the javac command I get this

```
C:\Users\AJ>javac
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried Fiddling with the path but no luck, and have restarted my PC etc. no luck

Also it seems to work if I am in the jdk\bin directory

```
C:\>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_25

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin>
```

how do I get javac command to run correctly like java is doing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had previously problems with the path containing a blank. I would suggest to change the path from

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

to

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to specify the full pathname.

Instead of

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

try

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin
```

This worked for me on Windows 10 64-bit Education Edition with Java 8.0.101